# SonarQube 6.2 Scanner is failing due to Error during parsing of coverage report /target/failsafe-reports:No such file or directory

Tags: sonarqube

we recently upgraded to version 6.2. 
GenericCoverage report is looking for a coverage report under /target/failsafe-reports, we are not running a coverage, just running a scanner. But still my Analysis fails due to the above error.

I notice as compare to our previous working SonarQube version 5.6 is,

Working Version 5.6:

```
[INFO] Sensor GenericCoverageSensor
[INFO] Imported coverage data for 0 files
[INFO] Parsing /target/failsafe-reports
[WARNING] Cannot find IT coverage report to parse: /target/failsafe-reports
[INFO] Sensor GenericCoverageSensor (done) | time=13ms
[INFO] Sensor Sonar-Sonargraph-Plugin [3.5]
```

It report the coverage report unable to find as Warning

Latest Version 6.2:

```
[INFO] Sensor Generic Coverage Report
[INFO] Parsing /target/failsafe-reports
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar (default-cli) on project rt: Error during parsing of coverage report /target/failsafe-reports: /target/failsafe-reports (No such file or directory) -> [Help 1]
```

So, even wothout providing any instruction to run a coverage report, sensor trying to look for the coverage report and it failed, as there was no code coverage report available.
Now, How to disable this behavior, to avoid looking for Coverage report?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling [Generic Test Coverage Plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Generic+Test+Coverage), this is deprecated and could be a point of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the leading slash: `target/failsafe-reports`, rather than `/target/failsafe-reports`.